# Functional WebDav client

Tags: windows-server-2003, webdav

I need to edit remotely folders located on Windows Server 2003. I read that webdav seems to behave quite unexpectedly with different versions of windows. Do you have some fully working solution with Windows7 64bit + Windows Server 2003 ?

If you are not for webdav, what do you recommend in this situation ? What protocol / client software?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

no client, just:

```
cmd net * use "https://server/webdav" /user:%username% %password%
```

works for me on my win7x64

Answer (score 0):

There are several good WebDAV clients available.  Two that come to mind are WebDrive and Expandrive.  WebDrive is a native 64bit application.  Not sure about Expandrive.  Here are the reviews on Spiceworks: [WebDrive](https://community.spiceworks.com/products/51476-webdrive) and [Expandrive](https://community.spiceworks.com/products/47296-expandrive?source=Selector_56)
NOTE: Spiceworks doesn't have a review category for WebDAV clients; both of these are listed under the FTP client category, but they do support WebDAV.